# Migrate RX to Coroutines

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I am starting to learn Coroutines
what this code will look like on Coroutines ? 
I would like to leave RX
and start using Coroutines

```
open class DataState<out T>(val newState: T, val oldState: T?, val json: String)
object EventBus {
    private val dataPublisher: MutableMap<String, PublishSubject<DataState<Any>>> = mutableMapOf()

    inline fun <reified T : Any> fire(event: DataState<T>) = fire(T::class.java.name, event)
    fun <T : Any> fire(clazz: Class<T>, event: DataState<T>) = EventBus.fire(clazz.name, event)

    fun <T : Any> fire(className: String, event: DataState<T>) {
        synchronized(this) {
            dataPublisher[className]?.onNext(event)
        }
    }

    inline fun <reified T : Any> on(): Observable<DataState<T>> = on(T::class.java)

    fun <T> on(dataType: Class<T>): Observable<DataState<T>> {

        synchronized(this) {
            var pub = dataPublisher[dataType.name]

            if (pub == null) {
                pub = PublishSubject.create()
                dataPublisher[dataType.name] = pub
            }

            return pub.ofType(DataState::class.java) as Observable<DataState<T>>
        }
    }

    fun reset() {
        synchronized(this) {
            dataPublisher.values.forEach { it.onComplete() }
            dataPublisher.clear()
        }
    }
}
```

I really have no idea how to do the same thing with Coroutines, but I'm willing to entertain the possibility that it will be an improvement. Could someone show me how this would be done with Coroutines, and explain what's better about the Coroutines way?

Comment: Coroutines address only one part of the universe that RxJava addresses. For instance, control of timing, threading, or flow control are much more difficult without RxJava.